# Give three distinct examples of linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ ("Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

> Exercise 3.F.2
> Give three distinct examples of linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$.

The only example which I can give is the following example:

> Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in [0,1]$.
> Let $c_1,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb{R}$.
> $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}\ni f\mapsto c_1f(a_1)+\dots+c_nf(a_n)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Please give me other two examples of linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: You have already given infinitely many.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much for your comment. Is there any other type example?

Comment: Assuming choice, here is one: pick a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ that extends the linearly independent collection of $\delta$-functions: $\delta_x(y) = 1$ if $y = x$ and $0$ otherwise. Your linear functionals map $\delta_{a_i}$ to $c_i$ and the infinitely many other $\delta_x$ to $0$. So mapping $f$ to the sum of the coefficients in the expression of $f$ in this basis defines a linear functional that is not one of the functionals you wrote down.

Comment: @ronno Thank you very much for your answer.